# Differences between x32 and x64 IDEs for development (eg Netbeans, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide, 32bit-64bit

What are the main differences when developing in java with x32 or x64 SDKs?
I've noticed that x64 versions of IDEs are consuming more RAM while running but I don't know if there are any benefits.

I don't know if there are any criteria that someone should have in mind when choosing between x64 and x32 software versions in general (not only for java development).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For example: x64 can address more than 3.xGB memory.